# Unable to parse XML from URL for indeed API

Tags: ios, xml, api, parsing

Well, i am using this library to parse xml: SwiftyXMLParser but unfortunately unable to get results array from the respond in IOS but i can see them on browser [see this link](http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=4935138002921571&q=ios&l=austin%2C%20tx&sort=&radius=&st=&jt=&start=&limit=&fromage=&filter=&latlong=1&co=us&chnl=&userip=1.2.3.4&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2) or [sample of respond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcEa0.png)!

This is my operation :

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    if let data = data {
        let xml = XML.parse(data)
        print(xml)
        //tried xml["results"]["0"] also didn't work
    }

}).resume()
```

This is my output in IOS :

```
<response version="2">
<query>ios</query>
<location>austin, tx</location>
<clickedCategories/>
<paginationPayload/>
<radius>25</radius>
<dupefilter>true</dupefilter>
<highlight>false</highlight>
<start>1</start>
<end>10</end>
<pageNumber>0</pageNumber>
<totalresults>315</totalresults>
<results>
//This is array but No results!!
<\results>
```

So does anyone knows why? and how?

Thank you.

my attempt with json:

let indeedAPI = "api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=4935138002921571&q=(searchTerm)&format=json&l=%2C+tx&sort=&radius=50&st=&jt=&start=&limit=10&fromage=&filter=&latlong=1&co=&chnl=&userip=1.2.3.4&v=2"

```
    let googleYoutubeAPIUrl = URL(string: indeedAPI.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!)

    let request:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: googleYoutubeAPIUrl!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5.0)

    OperationQueue.main.cancelAllOperations()
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        if let _ = error {
            print(error.debugDescription)
            return
        }

        if let data = data {
            completion(JSON(data: data))
        } else { print("data nil"); return }

    })
    task.resume()

{
  "paginationPayload" : "",
  "location" : "%2C tx",
  "dupefilter" : true,
  "results" : [
// also no results
  ],
  "totalResults" : 0,
  "version" : 2,
  "end" : 0,
  "pageNumber" : 0,
  "start" : 0,
  "query" : "ios developer",
  "highlight" : true
}
```

Comment: @Rob thank you, i've added my output

Comment: @Rob sorry again, i've edited my question. Thank you

Comment: Does `xml["results"]` even work?

Comment: @Rob tried google places api xml and worked fine but indeed api hmm it weird because my output(api respond) doesn't include results array

Comment: @Rob can u try indeed api and try to parse it ?

Comment: @Larme the results is nil but i can see them on the web

Comment: If you have a question about using JSON, then that should be a separate question, not combined in this SwiftyXMLParser question. I'd suggest removing the JSON attempt from here...

Comment: And, by the way, if you're going to edit this, I'd suggest fixing the typo in the `results` closing tag in your example XML above. You're using a backslash and it should be a slash.

Comment: @HamadFouad - By the way, you're missing the scheme (`http://` or `https://`) in your URL. That's required. Also, you're taking a query that is already percent escaped (e.g. `%2C`) and percent escaping it again. That can't be right. What value are you trying to send for `l`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the `result` entries, you can do something like:

```
let xml = XML.parse(data)

guard xml.error == nil else {
    print("\(xml.error!)")
    return
}

let results = xml["response", "results"]

guard results.error == nil && results["result"].error == nil else {
    print("no results")
    return
}

for result in results["result"] {
    if let jobtitle = result["jobtitle"].text {
        print("\(jobtitle)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method is correct but it will work if and only if the respond has results entries! it is weird because no results in the respond! this is my problem, why the respond cannot include the results in the respond? Thank you.

Comment: @HamadFouad - Then just add whatever `guard` statements you want. You can either do it like I have above (checking for `result` element), or add a `guard` statement for `totalResults` value.